# How to align text in the span to split to two lines using react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

i want to space the text within span element to two lines. for that i am using width for span element such that the text would wrap to two lines. how can i do the same without using width. also how can i better refactor the code below to something neat and not many repetitions.

Below is how it should look

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Below is the code,

```
interface Props {
    marginLeft?: number;  
}

function Childcomponent({ marginLeft }: Props) {
    return (
        <Wrapper marginLeft={marginLeft}>
            <Container>
                <Text size={12} weight={700} color={some_var}>
                    comp
                </Text>
                <Text size={12} color={some_var}>
                    companyname
                </Text>
            </Container>
            <Text size={25} weight={700} color={some_var}>
                {some_text}
            </Text>
            <Text size={14} weight={700} color={some_var}>
                /10
            </Text>
            <BooksText size={12}>
                book items
            </Booksext>
            <Text size={25} weight={700} color={some_var}>
                {some_text1}
            </Text>
            <Text size={14} weight={700} color={some_var}>
                /10
            </Text>
            <PensText size={12}>
                pen items count
            </PensText>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}

const Wrapper = styled.div<{ marginLeft?: number }>`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: ${props => props.marginLeft + 'px' || 0};
`;

 const Container = styled.div`
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     width: 162px;
     margin-left: 8px;
 `;

  const BooksText = styled(Text)`
      width: 58px;
      margin-left: 6px;
      margin-right: 8px;
  `;

   const PensText = styled(Text)`
       width: 65px;
       margin-left: 6px;
       margin-right: 8px;
  `;
```

This Text component returns a span element.

Could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: `<span>` elements are inline and don't have width properties unless you assign `display: inline-block;` to their styling.

Comment: thanks. so how do i set the span elements within the wrapper such that the book and pens text wrap to two lines.